# JMeter - malformed Cookies Exc when adding AWS Load balancer's AWSALB Cookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, jmeter

I need to do load testing on Amazon AWS cloud for an application which requires Sticky sessions. AWS ELB sends a cookie called AWSALB for sticky sessions.

JMeter is not able to add the cookie as it finds it to be malformed. I do not want to run the test without disabling Sticky sessions, hence, the cookie will exist. How do i make sure JMeter accepts this cookie?

Typical Cookie:

```
AWSALB=Xvt/JIiJPAVz4+lK8F+ULq2317adfZ/mRzKPEzQ2gH7PBJU77S8eUZpZpleVCm6ooYzkhyxA5eUIkCOSOB4jIoKzLYG71rtQ9y9/F/OWJRYgHMKiCCD0p122YUyn; Expires=Mon, 24 Jun 2019 11:23:51 GMT; Path=/
```

Error in JMeter log:

```
2019-06-17 16:53:54,532 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: Invalid 'expires' attribute: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 11:23:54 GMT at 
org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicExpiresHandler.parse(BasicExpiresHandler.java:64) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3] at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.CookieSpecBase.parse(CookieSpecBase.java:113) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3] at 
org.apache.http.impl.cookie.NetscapeDraftSpec.parse(NetscapeDraftSpec.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
```